# How to stay the activity layout when using SwipeBackLayout

Tags: android

Recently, I am using the SwipeBackLayout on github here https://github.com/Issacw0ng/SwipeBackLayout

I have two activity: A and B, B extends SwipeBackActivity, A start Activity B. Also set the theme of B : `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`

When swipe the left edge of B, it should return A and the background when B is swiping should be A. But the background when B is swiping is the desktop of my phone? Can anyone explain this?

Here is the B Activity -- BackActivity

```
public class BackActivity extends SwipeBackActivity {

    private SwipeBackLayout swipeBackLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_back);
        swipeBackLayout = getSwipeBackLayout();
        swipeBackLayout.setEdgeTrackingEnabled(SwipeBackLayout.EDGE_LEFT);
    }
}
```

And the A Activity -- MainAcitity

```
public class MainActivity extends SwipeBackActivity {

    private SwipeBackLayout swipeBackLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        swipeBackLayout = getSwipeBackLayout();
        swipeBackLayout.setEdgeTrackingEnabled(SwipeBackLayout.EDGE_LEFT);

    }

    public void GoClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get the new version,add to your project.Notice style.xml with `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`,just do it,it's easy